# Unity Tilemap generating tile chunks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do level generation with tilemap.
I have painted in tilemap different tile chunks like platforms, walls, ground block etc. Is it possible to somehow save this chunks (like prefabs or something) and generate them via script?

Comment: You can save tilemaps you have made as prefabs, my question is what have you tried to figure this out yourself?

Comment: @Eddge I don't need to prefab whole tilemaps, but only several painted tiles